# Increment and Decrement value in textbox label value

Tags: c#, jquery

```js
 <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btn2").click(function () {
                var $n = $("#number");
                $n.val(Number($n.val()) + 50); // Have to type the .val() response to a number instead of a string.
            });
        });
    </script>
```

```html
 <asp:Label ID="lblcost" runat="server" Text="50/-" />
 <input type="text" id="number" value="0"/>
 <button id="btn2" type="button">+</button>
```

i am writing the code by using javascript, jquery, html, c#.

I have taken one label value is 50. and two buttons for increment and decrement.
What i want is "when i click on the Increment button the value is displayed in textbox which is what i given the label value. if i click on first time on increment button the textbox value is 50, 2nd time it's become 100. if i click on decrement button it's become 100-50=50. but

it has to take that particular label value.

Please provide the exact code for this task

```js
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btn2").click(function () {
                var $n = $("#number");
                $n.val(Number($n.val()) + 50); 
            });
        });
 </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<asp:Label ID="lblcost" runat="server" Text="50/-" />
        <input type="text" id="number" value="0"/>
        <button id="btn2" type="button">+</button>
```

Comment: Any efforts ...? And I see upvote for this question:(

Comment: Mr Ravi is demanding code without any efforts

Answer (score 0):

did one code ,try this if any changes ping me...[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7g6ccpdw/1/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 var label=parseInt($("#label1").html());
 alert(label);
            $("#Incre").click(function () {          
                $("#number").val(parseInt($("#number").val())+label);    
            });
            $("#Decre").click(function () {          
                 if($("#number").val()>0){
                     $("#number").val(parseInt($("#number").val())-label);    
                  }  
            });
});

<label id='label1'>50</label>
<input id='number' value=0></input>
<button  id='Incre'>Incre</button>
<button  id='Decre'>Decre</button>
```

Comment: thank u it's working. but When textbox value is zero . if i click on decrement button the textbox value is going to negitive values . how to control this one.

Comment: I have updated the code, just put one condition in Decre event function.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 <script>
        function x(){
 var a=$("#vara").val();
 a++;
 $("#varb").val(a); 
}
 </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Before Increment :</label>
<input type="text" id="vara" onchange="x();">

<label>After Increment :</label>
<input type="text" id="varb">
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks